# Program exit after trying to allocate memory without error

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

I have a weird problem with a piece of code(it's not written by me, I m stil trying to understand)

```
template<typename T>
T &
ThreadLocalStorage<T>::instance () const
{
    T *pValue = static_cast<T *>(TlsGetValue(m_index));
    auto x = GetLastError();
    if (pValue == 0) {
        int size = sizeof(T);
        pValue = new T();
        TlsSetValue(m_index, pValue);
    }
    return *pValue;
}
```

The problem is that after allocating memory to `pValue = new T();` the program just exits without showing a single error, a breakpoing or heap corruption.
I tried to allocate memory separately with

```
 void *ptr = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T));
 pValue = new(ptr) T;
```

and it crash on malloc, in `locks.cpp` at the function

```
extern "C" void __cdecl __acrt_lock(_In_ __acrt_lock_id _Lock)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&__acrt_lock_table[_Lock]);
}
```

It seems that `__acrt_lock_table` variable is NULL, nothing in memory, and I can't go further in `EnterCriticalSection`, it seems that i has two references for this function.
How can I find out what cause the problem and what would be the solution?

Comment: You mess up something somewhere else, not in the code you show. Possible  somewhere there's an uninitialized or otherwise invalid pointer or array index you use. At the very least, all we can currently say is that you have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `void *ptr = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T));` - No. Don't try to allocate memory for C++ objects with `malloc`.

Comment: "the program just exits without showing a single error, a breakpoing or heap corruption" - If your program contains Undefined Behaviour *anywhere*, then there are no longer *any* guarantees as to what may happen. *Anything* is allowed. And no, the compiler is *not* abliged to tell you that you broke the rules (and your program - *you* have to know and follow the rules).